# The ViewData item that has the key 'category' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am new to asp.net MVC, I hope someone can help. 
I try to change the category field of the create form to a dorpdownlist.
The items of the dropdownlist come from a table - Catagory

Everything seem fine, but When I submit to create, I got the error message

> The ViewData item that has the key 'category' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Here is my Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Catagorys
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {

            Text = c.CatagoryName

        });

        ViewBag.Searchcategory = items;
        return View();
 } 

    //
    // POST: /Admin/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Contact contact)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes, Try again.");

        }

        return View(contact);
    }
```

And here is my Create View Code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.category, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Searchcategory, "--Select One--")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category)
</div>
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Catagorys` I think your data table is misspelled.

Comment: while passing `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, also include `Value` property of `SelectListItem` - its a good practice to follow.

Answer (score 1):

In post, if ModelState is invalid, you return view. But you fill categories select list only in get request, you should do that in post too

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Contact contact)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Contacts.Add(contact);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes, Try again.");

    }

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Catagorys
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {

        Text = c.CatagoryName

    });

    return View(contact);
}
```

And of course, it will be great if you create `CreateContactViewModel` class, with selectlist property inside. And get rid of using ViewBag

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Anyhow, it still not working. It looks like when I pick a choice from the SelectListItem. the choice will not update to the entity model.

Comment: That is another problem already : ). Post your Contract class and html of generated html select, including its options. 

And as it seems, you are not filling Value of SelectListItem